# Boolean parameter in Oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

This is the signature of my Oracle function

```
 FUNCTION functionName(
     param1 VARCHAR2, 
     param2 VARCHAR2, 
     param3 DATE, 
     param4 DATE, 
     param5 BOOLEAN) 
 RETURN myOwnType;
```

I use it :

```
myOwnTypeVar := functionName('something', 'some', SYSDATE, SYSDATE, TRUE);
```

I have this error :

```
PLS-00382 expression is of wrong type.
```

All the types seem to be respected. I wonder if I can use Boolean parameter in function (there was no problem using it in procedures).

Thank you.

Note : Declaration of myOwnTypeVar

```
myOwnTypeVar myOwnType;
```

Comment: does the return type match the type of the variable?

Comment: how is myOwnTypeVar declared?

Comment: The problem is not the Boolean parameter. Show more of your code - especially around the line mentioned in the error message. The error message should tell you where the error occurred (at which line in the code).

Comment: If you want specific help you will need to post the code for `functionname` and the declaration of `myOwntype`.

Answer (score 1):

> " I wonder if I can use Boolean parameter in function "

Yes. PL/SQL supports Boolean datatype. If `myOwnType` is a PL/SQL record like this ...

```
create or replace package p23 as
    type myOwnType is record (
        attr1 varchar2(10), 
        attr2 varchar2(30), 
        attr3 date, 
        attr4 date, 
        attr5 boolean
     );
    function functionname(
        param1 varchar2, 
        param2 varchar2, 
        param3 date, 
        param4 date, 
        param5 boolean) 
    return myowntype;    
end p23;
/
create or replace package body p23 as
    function functionname(
        param1 varchar2, 
        param2 varchar2, 
        param3 date, 
        param4 date, 
        param5 boolean) 
        return myowntype
    is
        rv myOwnType;
    begin
        rv.attr1 := param1;
        rv.attr2 := param2;
        rv.attr3 := param3;
        rv.attr4 := param4;
        rv.attr5 := param5;
        return rv;
    end;
end p23;
/
```

... there's no problem:

```
SQL> declare
  2    myOwnTypeVar p23.myowntype;
  3  begin
  4    myOwnTypeVar := p23.functionName('something', 'some', SYSDATE, SYSDATE, TRUE);
  5  end;
  6  /   

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So what causes the error? `PLS-00382` is an assignment failure. You haven't posted the declaration of `myOwnType` but if it was defined with a string attribute instead of a boolean, like this ...

```
    type myOwnType is record (
        attr1 varchar2(10), 
        attr2 varchar2(30), 
        attr3 date, 
        attr4 date, 
        attr5 varchar2(1)
     );
```

... then this assignment would throw that error:

```
   rv.attr5 := param5;
```

---

As an aside Oracle SQL does not support Boolean, even for Types:

```
SQL> create or replace type myOwnType as object (
  2        attr1 varchar2(10), 
  3        attr2 varchar2(30), 
  4        attr3 date, 
  5        attr4 date, 
  6        attr5 boolean
  7  );
/   

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for TYPE MYOWNTYPE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/8      PLS-00530: Illegal type used for object type attribute:
         'BOOLEAN'.

SQL>
```

In this scenario `functionName()` would not compile so could not hurl `PLS-00382 expression is of wrong type`.

Comment: In what way is it being a SQL type relevant here? This is a PL/SQL function, and the fact that it has a boolean parameter only means it cannot be called from SQL; but this shouldn't stop it being called from PL/SQL.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - you're right now. Originally it was there because of the answer from Damian (since deleted but you got the rep).  The root is, the OP didn't include the **definition of the type** in their original question and hasn't bothered to respond to our questions.

Comment: I see. Fair enough.